# Why does view_interface::data const overload need an extra check that const D satisfies ranges::range?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

According to [[view.interface]](http://eel.is/c++draft/view.interface), non-const and const overloaded `data` functions are defined as follows:

```
template<class D>
  requires is_class_v<D> && same_­as<D, remove_cv_t<D>>
class view_interface : public view_base {
private:
  constexpr D& derived() noexcept {                   // exposition only
    return static_cast<D&>(*this);
  }
  constexpr const D& derived() const noexcept {       // exposition only
    return static_cast<const D&>(*this);
  }
public:
  constexpr auto data() requires contiguous_­iterator<iterator_t<D>> {
    return to_address(ranges::begin(derived()));
  }
  constexpr auto data() const
    requires range<const D> && contiguous_­iterator<iterator_t<const D>> {
      return to_address(ranges::begin(derived()));
    }
};
```

Why does `data() const` need to additionally satisfy that `const D` is a [`ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range)?
Isn't [`iterator_t<const D>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iterator_t) already restricted so that `const D` must be a `ranges::range`?

What is the real purpose of `requires range<const D>` here? Is there a situation where `D` is a `ranges::range` and `const D` is not a `ranges::range`?

Comment: For your first question: They aren't same. `ranges::range<const D>` requires implementing `ranges::end(const D&)` in addition to `ranges::begin(const D&)`, while `iterator<const D>` only requires the latter. Not sure why one would need `ranges::end` for `data() const` though.

Comment: @ofo. Does this mean that it is legal to use `view_interface` to wrap a _non-range_ class that cannot use `ranges::end`? I don't even know what the purpose is...

Comment: I don't think so [since](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.utility#view.interface.general-2) "The template parameter `D` for `view_­interface` [...] shall [...] model [...] `view`." and `view` [requires](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.view#concept:view) `range`.

Comment: *Is there a situation where `D` is `ranges::range` and `const D` is not `ranges::range`?* https://godbolt.org/z/4oYKTPKTK

Comment: @metalfox. Oh, this is the case why `data() const` should be forbidden, thank you!

Comment: @metalfox. But in this case, `ranges::iterator_t<const my_vector>` will still be ill-formed, so I think the purpose of `ranges::range<const D>` is just to block it early.

Comment: Yes. `my_vector` is a range, but `const my_vector` isn't.